# Hot Network Questions is now a bulleted list

Tags: bug, status-completed

Something changed, and now the HNQ list in the sidebar is a bulleted list:

> [image]

This looks a little awkward to me, since the site icons already do the job of a bullet. I don't see this happening on any other site, either (it's only Academia and Meta Academia).

Is this a bug?

Comment: I see it also. Am asking around.

Comment: ......... Yuck.

Comment: It appears to be specific to Academia. Other sites are not showing this.

Comment: @StrongBad any update on this? It's been a while.

Comment: @Hosea I asked the SE team to look at it. I will try and follow up again in a couple of more days. The SE team periodically checks on questions tagged *bug*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. There was some weird custom styling for `UL` and `OL` elements in sidebar. Should be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) with next build (in couple hours probably).

Comment: Looks fixed to me. Thanks for taking care of us.

Comment: But why does it happen specific on Academia?